# Sort object that contains List and update object using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I am writing a function to sort a `List` using a property inside the list. 
I need to sort the `MyClass` object `obj` using the property `Age` of the list `AnimalList` and assign the sorted list back to `obj`. After performing the function `obj` should get updated with the new sorted object. My list value has got the sorted list now. I need to update that to obj.

I have tried many possibilities but couldn't bind it the list to the object.

```
public void SortBlocks(MyClass obj)
{
    List<Animal> value = obj.AnimalList;
    value = value.OrderBy(val => val.Age).ToList();
}

public interface MyClass 
{
     List<Animal> AnimalList { get; set; }
}
public class Animal
{
    public string color{get;set;}
    public uint Age{get;set;}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how do you initialize the list? why don't you order the list when initializing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
List<Animal> value = obj.AnimalList;
obj.AnimalList = value.OrderBy(x => x.Age).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have generated a new collection object by ordering the animals.  To see the sorted results in obj after calling SortBlocks, you need to assign value back to obj.AnimalList:

```
public static void SortBlocks(MyClass obj)
{
    List<Animal> value = obj.AnimalList;
    value = value.OrderBy(val => val.Age).ToList();
    obj.AnimalList = value;
}
```

Edit: By the way, you can just do an in-place sort like so:

```
public static void SortBlocks(MyClass obj)
{
    obj.AnimalList.Sort(new Comparison<Animal>((x, y) => x.Age.CompareTo(y.Age)));
}
```